# java url connection set cookie

Tags: java, php, url, cookies, connection

I followed Ian Brown's tutorial to set a cookie to a request http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html

but it don't works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
public class cookie {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    URL myUrl = null;
    try {
        myUrl = new URL("http://server/test.php?hlp");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        URLConnection con = myUrl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "accesstoken=WERT-DES-COOKIES");
        con.connect();
        String line;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         builder.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(builder);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

the php-test-Script returns the $_REQUEST-values... but I only get the "hlp"-Parameter given in the URL. Can somebody tell me whats wrong?!

Comment: If you want to do HTTP, you should try and have a look at Apache's httpclient library -- unless you have a hard requirement to use only what the JDK provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you are using  $_REQUEST to retrieve the cookies. Please note that `$_REQUEST` will retrieve **only request parameters** either passed as query string or as POST request. To retrieve cookie use `$_COOKIE` associative array. Check [this tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php).

Comment: you're totally right... I'm such a damn idiot :-( the skript above works, the php-Script was the problem